# In ASP.net MVC, where to put the code that I want to execute once? (initialize)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a standard ASP.net MVC 5 project, where do I put the code that I want to execute once "on system startup"?

Thanks!

Comment: You can put it on the Global.asax.cs. In the Application_Start